# Delete Everything in a Directory Except One FIle - Using SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, escaping, rm

In BASH, the following command removes everything in a directory except one file:

```
rm -rf !(filename.txt)
```

However, in SSH the same command changes nothing in the directory and it returns the following error: **-jailshell: !: event not found**

So, I escaped the `!` with `\`, (the parentheses also require escaping) but it still doesn't work:

```
rm -rf \!\(filename.txt\)
```

It returns no error and nothing in the directory changed.

Is it even possible to run this command in SSH? I found a workaround but if this is possible it would expedite things considerably.

I connect to the ssh server using the alias below:

```
alias devssh="ssh -p 2222 -i ~/.ssh/private_key user@host"
```

Comment: Please add your ssh command to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, it's there. It's the second code block.

Comment: I think Cyrus meant the full `ssh` command (i.e. `ssh user@host ...`) not just the command that runs inside ssh.

Comment: Where does `-jailshell:` come from?

Comment: @Cyrus, it's returned in the Terminal window.

Comment: I think the remote system's default shell is called `jailshell`, and that shell complains about `!(...)`.

Comment: @Socowi, I use a private key to connect to the server so I do not have to start with ssh.

Comment: Please add output of `ssh user@host 'echo $BASH_VERSION'` to your question.

Comment: *"I do not have to start with ssh"* -- Um... not sure I understood that right. Are you saying, to execute `cmd` on a remote machine, you don't have to write `ssh ... cmd` but instead write just `cmd`? How could your local shell ever know that you want to execute this command on the remote machine instead?

Comment: @Cyrus, there BASH version: 4.1.2(2)-release

Comment: @Cyrus I setup an alias in .bash_profile to connect me quickly so I don't have to type `ssh user@host` every time I issue a command.

Comment: Please add your alias to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus, it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!(filename.txt)` is an extglob, a bash future that might have to be enabled. Make sure that your ssh server runs bash and that extglob is enabled:

```
ssh user@host "bash -O extglob -c 'rm -rf !(filename.txt)'"
```

Or by using your alias:

```
devssh "bash -O extglob -c 'rm -rf !(filename.txt)'"
```

If you are sure that the remote system uses bash by default, you can also drop the `bash -c` part. But your error message indicates that the ssh server runs `jailshell`.

```
ssh user@host 'shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(filename.txt)'
devssh 'shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(filename.txt)'
```

Comment: I tried to set the extglob using `bash -O extglob -c 'rm -rf !(filename.txt)` and it blew away all the contents in the entire public_html directory.

Comment: Seems about right if there was no `filename.txt` in that directory. Are you sure such a file was there before?

Comment: @Thomas: I suggest to replace `rm` with `echo rm` first.

Comment: [Here is a local test](https://onlinegdb.com/n9lPRynYs), showing that the command works as expected.

Comment: I'll just be quite glad it's a dev server.

Comment: @Socowi, as I said in the question, I know it works fine in BASH. It does not work when I'm logged in to the server via SSH.

Comment: You said you executed `bash -O extglob -c 'rm -rf !(filename.txt)'` **through ssh (?)**, and that this command deleted everything. That means that you (1) ran bash **on the remote system** (2) the command worked. Therefore, I don't understand why this question is still open. What else do you need? *(Only if you confirmed that `bash -O extglob -c 'touch filename.txt; rm -rf !(filename.txt); ls'` deleted `filename.txt` too I would see a problem. But then I would need more information, because I cannot reproduce such a problem, as shown by my prev. comment)*

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it that way.  I wouldn't rely on bash being on the remote, and I wouldn't rely on any bashisms.  I would use:

```
$ ssh user@host 'rm $(ls | grep -v "^filename.txt$")'
```

If I wanted to protect against the possibility that the directory might be empty, I'd assign the output of `$(...)` to a  variable, and test it for emptiness.  If I was concerned the command might get too long, I'd write the names to a file, and send the **grep** output to **rm** with **xargs**.

If it got too elaborate, I'd copy a script to the remote and execute it.

Comment: I would be concerned for more than a long command. If you had the files `important.txt` and `not important.txt` and you ran `rm $(ls | grep -v "^important.txt$")` then you would be in for a [surprise](https://onlinegdb.com/l4Kd8FYf7).

Comment: **ls** written to a pipe produces one line per name.  `^important.txt$` matches the whole line, anchored at the front by `^`. It doesn't match `not important.txt`, which `grep -v` will print because the sense is inverted.

Comment: Yes, this is all correct. But did you try it for yourself (see link in my previous comment). The problem is the unquoted `$()` which undergoes **word**splitting. `not important.txt` then turns into `not` and `important.txt`. Also, globs in filenames will expand.

Comment: @Socowi, thanks, I see your point now. I would still follow my advice, to use standard syntax, and yours, to test carefully, especially with **rm**(1).